# switch case JavaScript: Variable Django no es reconocida

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

tengo una funcion  que hace un switch case para selecccionar un tiempo especifico para determinado elemento. El problema es que los cases los genero en base a la  cantidad de elementos en la base de datos usando el ID como numero de caso.

ejemplo:

```
swicth(---metodod de API de FOTORAMA -- ){
    case {{image.id}}:
    //assignacion de tiempos
}
```

se que la expresion dentro del case es correcto ya que si le hago un  console.log(); veo el id que se supone debe de hacer match con los casos

el problema que es no activa ninguo de los ejemplo de mis  funcion

ejemplo codigo dinamico:

```
$(function () {
      $('.fotorama').on('fotorama:showend',function(){
            console.log(fotorama.activeFrame.id);

            switch(fotorama.activeFrame.id){

                {% for imagen in imagenes %}
                case {{ imagen.id }}:

                    fotorama.setOptions({
                        autoplay : {{ imagen.duracion }}
                    });
                    break;
                {% endfor %}

                default:
                    fotorama.setOptions({
                        autoplay: 2000
                    });
                    break;
            }
        })
    });
```

codigo  ya generado :

```
$(function () {
      $('.fotorama').on('fotorama:showend',function(){
            console.log(fotorama.activeFrame.id);

            switch(fotorama.activeFrame.id){


                case 44:

                    fotorama.setOptions({
                        autoplay : 5000
                    });
                    break;

                case 45:

                    fotorama.setOptions({
                        autoplay : 20000
                    });
                    break;


                default:
                    fotorama.setOptions({
                        autoplay: 2000
                    });
                    break;
            }
        })
    });

getSlides();
```

y esto es lo que obtengo en consola :
[image: screenshot consola inspector]

Answer (score -1):

En JavaScript el elemento `switch` solo recibe parámetros de tipo Entero por lo que si conviertes la variable `fotorama.activeFrame.id` antes de que pase al `swicth` con un `parseInt` funcionará.

Por ejemplo:

```
switch(parseInt(fotorama.activeFrame.id)){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Vale, ya profundicé mejor la explicación

Comment: Switch funciona con tipo strings de igual forma